# Why is a 2-year bond not a good store of nominal value?

Tags: investing, bonds

I was recently confronted with the following question:

Which of the following is not a good store of nominal value?

- a: checking deposit
- b: savings deposit
- c: 1 2-year bond
- d: a 3-month CD

The answer I was given is C.

Can someone explain why this is the correct answer?

Comment: Could you look at each in terms of principal risk? That would likely be my initial thought as "good store of nominal value" would be choices where there is little risk to the principal.

Comment: Perhaps it is because C is the only one that is not federally insured (in the U.S.).

Comment: Why do you assume jxhyc is in the US? Or that the bond isn't a Treasury (which they should have called a 'note')

Comment: I would be surprised if there was a country that would insure corporate bonds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per investopedia [Nominal value](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/n/nominalvalue.asp) is the value printed on a security and not calculated.

> A nominal value is the stated value of an issued security. Nominal value – also known as face value or par value in reference to securities – disregards an item's market value. Measurements of economic growth and personal income that do not adjust for inflation are nominal values, while measurements that adjust for inflation are real values.

If we add this with [Store of Value](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/storeofvalue.asp);

> A store of value is any form of wealth that maintains its value without depreciating. Commodities such as gold and other forms of metal are good stores of value, as their shelf lives are essentially perpetual, whereas a good such as milk is a terrible store of value due to its natural process of spoilage. Interest-bearing assets, such as U.S. Treasury bonds, are very good stores of value, because they generate an income of their own and their principal value is backed by a legal contract.

Thus a bond may loose / gain its nominal value printed at the time of issue and hence "c" is the answer.